# VueJS cli-plugin-typescript: import template files failes

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've already installed [cli-plugin-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript).

Anything works fine **but the template import failes** with type `.html` or `.tpl`.

Before the plugin, the import works well:

```
// ~/Test/index.js
import tpl from "./template.tpl";
import './style.scss';
...

export default {
    name: 'Test',
    template: tpl,
    ...
}
```

The config for `tpl` type:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['@vue/cli-service'],
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {

    config.module
      .rule('tpl')
      .test(/\.tpl$/)
      .use('html-loader')
      .loader('html-loader');

    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now the *same* file as `.ts`

```
// ~/Test/index.ts
...
const tpl = require("./template.tpl").default; // try with template.html failed also
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    template: tpl, // ===> using "<div><h2>Dummy TS</h2></div>" instead the import, it works
    ...
})
```

The answer/error:

```
ERROR in ./src/module/Test/template.html 1:0
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div>
|         <button v-on:click="decrement">decrement</button>
```

It seems all about the **config at the *right* place**.

Where and how to solve this?